# write recursive Parser with pyparsing

Tags: python, parsing, pyparsing

I'm trying to understand the `Forward()` element from pyparsing. Suppose I have this simple BNF:

```
identifier  =
  "a..z,$,_"  <  "a..z,$,_,0..9"  >

package_name = 
  identifier 
  /  ( package_name  "." identifier )
```

and I try to parse a simple package like `java.lang.String` I get either just `java` as result or never return from recursion.
I tried it like this:

```
from pyparsing import alphas,alphanums, Word, Forward, ZeroOrMore, Group, Literal

identifier=Word(alphas+"$_",alphanums+"$_")
dot=Literal(".")

package_name = Forward()
definition = package_name+dot+identifier
package_name << Group(identifier+ZeroOrMore(definition))

package_name.parseString("java.lang.String")
```

will print [['java']]

```
from pyparsing import alphas,alphanums, Word, Forward, ZeroOrMore, Group, Literal

identifier=Word(alphas+"$_",alphanums+"$_")
dot=Literal(".")

package_name = Forward()
definition = identifier^package_name+dot+identifier
package_name << definition

package_name.parseString("java.lang.String")
```

will reach recursion limit

how does this `Forward` placeholder work?

Comment: Why don't you just do `package_name = ZeroOrMore(identifier+dot) + identifier`?  I think the problem with what you're doing is that it's recurise *and* involves ZeroOrMore, which allows it to keep on matching zero.  Your original BNF has no equivalent of ZeroOrMore.  But it's simpler to avoid recursion altogether.

Comment: i know i could do it another way. like `delimitedList(identifier,delim=".")` but I want to understand the `Forward` recursion ParserElement. Even `package_name << definition` won't work

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is not with `Forward` but with your grammar, which is inherently either limited too early, or recursive in a way that is undecidable with a naive recursive descent parser like Pyparsing.

You have this:

```
package_name = identifier | (package_name "." identifier )
```

If you match left to right, this will always match a single identifier and then stop, without attempting to match a following period.  If you switch the order to match the `identifier` last:

```
package_name = (package_name "." identifier) | identifier
```

. . . then it will infinitely recurse, because in order to decide if `package_name` matches, the first thing it has to do is decide whether `package_name` matches.  This is a [left-recursive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_recursion) grammar, which a simple recursive-descent parser like Pyparsing can't handle.  Pyparsing does not look ahead to see how a match will affect subsequent matches.  It just tries the matches left to right.

You can get a simple example of how `Forward` works by changing the way your grammar recurses:

```
identifier  = pyp.Word(pyp.alphas+"$_", pyp.alphanums+"$_")
package_name = pyp.Forward()
package_name << ((identifier + '.' + package_name) | identifier)

>>> package_name.parseString("java.lang.String")
[u'java', u'.', u'lang', u'.', u'String'], {})
```

Here, the recursion happens on the right, not on the left, so Pyparsing can match it incremenetally.

(Your use of ZeroOrMore is a red herring.  If you're going to have a recursive grammar like this, you don't want to use ZeroOrMore, because the recursive definition already allows your sub-expression to match multiple times.  As I suggested in my comment, though, it is much simpler to define this sort of grammar without recursion anyway.)